# Finite $p$-groups of maximal class whose generators have order $p$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of maximal nilpotency class that is not cyclic of order $p^2$. Then $G$ is $2$-generated, say $G=\langle a,b\rangle$. Is there a classification in the case when $a^p=b^p=1$? Comments appreciated.